# How to use double await in Async function

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

```
self.ws = await self.client.ws_connect()#Aiohttp client session
self.rx_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(self._rx_task())
self.file_writer = await aiofiles.open('server_log.txt', 'wb')
self.rx_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    async def _rx_task(self):
        """
        Async function to collect the task and put into queue.
        """
        try:
            while True:
                msg = await self.ws.receive_json()
                #print(msg)
                await self.file_writer.write(msg)
                self.rx_queue.put_nowait(msg)
                return msg
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
```

I'm trying to get the json received from ws and write to a file before putting it into que. Printing the message works but I don't know why I'can't make it to write to file after commenting the print(). Can somebody help?

I've been learning how async works but if somebody can explain the problem, that would be appreciated