# How to use multiple await in AsyncIO function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

```
self.ws = await self.client.ws_connect()#Aiohttp client session
self.rx_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(self._rx_task())
self.file_writer = await aiofiles.open('server_log.txt', 'wb')
self.rx_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    async def _rx_task(self):
        """
        Async function to collect the task and put into queue.
        """
        try:
            while True:
                msg = await self.ws.receive_json()
                #print(msg)
                await self.file_writer.write(msg)
                self.rx_queue.put_nowait(msg)
              
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
```

I’m getting stuck on file_writer.write(). I want to write msg received from ws to a file before putting it to queue

Comment: 1. "getting stuck on" isn't really telling us much. What's happening? 2. You don't mention any extra modules. Where is `async_open` coming from? 3. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, please, fix the indentation in this snippet. If the other `self.xxxx = ....` statements are merely ilustrative, put then correctly indented in an `__init__`  method, add the class station, and any imports needed. Other than that, this code is almost fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP also asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334652/how-to-use-double-await-in-async-function